# Что значит "блазить"?

Tags: значение-слов

"Гардемарины III" (Екатерина говорит Елизавете):

> Мне судьба Анны Леопольдовны не ***блазит,*** и Павлушу я вам не отдам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Меня судьба Анны Леопольдовны не соблазняет (привлекает),

Я "Гардемаринов" не люблю (за странноватый, совсем не по эпохе язык - в т. ч.), видел только первую часть - и то не до конца. Могу только догадываться о контексте, в котором эта фраза прозвучала. Но в любом случае - весьма сомнительно, что в речи особ столь высокопоставленных употреблено значение, которое и у Даля-то не на первом месте идет среди диалектных. У него даже не очень понятно, является ли слово родственным "блажь", "соблазн" - или это случайное созвучие. Плюс ко всему не совсем по смыслу подходит.

> Мне судьба Анны Леопольдовны не блазит, и Павлушу я вам не отдам.

Точного синонима, боюсь, нет, "блазить" - это и есть блазить - делать что-то приятное, радовать, "счастливить" (осчастливливать). На крайний случай - вдохновлять. Согласитесь, даже в примере на картинке у G. A. куда более по смыслу подходит. "Соблазнять", "привлекать" - это уже меньшая степень точности.

Слово, увы, не фиксируется современными словарями, да и в "высоких", не диалектных текстах XVIII и даже XIX века встречается нечасто.

Однако в современных изданиях можно найти примеры правильного употребления.

> Олеся в ответ равнодушно пожала плечами, пусть болтают, ей к людям
> возвращаться неохота и делать там особо нечего. Насмотрелась на
> страшный каторжный труд крестьянок, их мужей - пьющих и бьющих,
> выводок орущих голодных детей. Нет, ей такая жизнь не блазит, на
> хуторе распрекрасно одна проживет.

Светлана Крамальская "Черные белые ночи"

> Вот Ягужинский тоже был денщиком, а стал генерал-прокурором Сената.
> Может, и Василию то блазит?

Андрианова Т. В. "Офицер и царевна. Вольная пташка"
(тот же автор, кстати, что и в примере у G. A., что позволяет говорить о характерном употреблении).

> Даже не знаю, что мне больше блазит?) То, что так здорово прошло
> выступление или то, что наконец- то я нашла удобное прибежище своим
> ногам, гудящим после концерта, как провода под высоким напряжением!)

Пользователь VK, пунктуация сохранена.

Ну никак в этих примерах не "соблазняет", а вот "радует" - вполне.

Выскажу предположение, что это значение на том этапе вполне соответствовало общему "чудиться". Два современных значения морфа "чуд" ("сверхъестественное" и "прекрасное") вполне удачно иллюстрируют этот переход.

Comment: Спасибо, читаю! *...За странноватый, совсем не по эпохе язык* — например "ёкарный бабай", да?))) А-а, это в последнем фильме (теперь прочитал, что вы первый только смотрели).

Comment: Нет, совсем не это. Понимаете, в исторических произведениях герои должны говорить либо языком своей эпохи (по склерозу - это последовательно проводил Мережковский), либо уж современным автору языком (без явных ахронизмов, естественно; у Гоголя это доведено до совершенства), А если взять это кино (которое, впрочем, и от литературного первоисточника недалеко ушло) и выкинуть имена собственные, то не сразу и поймешь, в какую эпоху попал. Стилизация то ли под XVI век, то ли под XIX... Каша. Это субъективно, ибо общее неприятие и романов, и фильма, конечно, не способствует взвешенному анализу стиля

Comment: Вспомнил еще один близкий синоним - "радовать" и заодно чуть поправил ответ.

Comment: Кстати, я тоже совершенно не хотел фильм смотреть, стиль не понравился, а потом втянулся, увлёкся сюжетом, понравились герои и закрыл глаза на то, что не нравилось. Так, получается, среди правильных значений и "осчастливливать", и "чудиться"?

Comment: Ээээ.... Ну да. "Чудиться" - это не "среди", это вообще главное значение. Но в разбираемом контексте оно не проходит.  "Осчастливливать" - это не очень точный синоним для вспомогательного значения, все наши примеры - именно на него,Э на это вспомогательное значение...

Answer (score 5):

На современном:

*Меня судьба Анны Леопольдовны не соблазняет (привлекает), и Павлушу я вам не отдам.*

---

[**БЛАЗН**](http://slovardalja.net/word.php?wordid=1876)

> БЛАЗН м. или блазнь ж. церк. соблазн, соблазнительные слова, поступки;
> мана, морока, обаяние. Блазнить кого, чем, соблазнять, искушать,
> смущать, совращать, наводить на грех; -ся, вдаваться, впадать в
> соблазн, быть соблазняему. Блазнить меня нечистый, в другой раз
> привиделся. Не блазнитесь вином-то, парья. Блазнить безличн. сев.
> блазнить. Поколе в чашке есть (недоедено), все блазнит.

По ссылке приведены и другие значения.

---

[БЛАЗИТЬ - БЛАЗНИТЬ](https://books.google.ru/books?id=6cHSAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA237&lpg=PA237&dq=%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%20-%20%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82&source=bl&ots=JLRHVzANgi&sig=ACfU3U2eTS9lr0cqZ36BEis0q3sbfhUTxA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiCvpLirYzqAhU1xMQBHaSzAXEQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, Галина! Что-то смущает меня запятая в примере с картинки после "тем более". Нужна она, кто что думает?

Comment: *Что-то смущает меня запятая в примере с картинки после "тем более". Нужна она, кто что думает?* Не нужна. Формально-то её можно оправдать тем, что "тем более" в беллетристике часто используется как вводное, но здесь такое использование очень неестественно.  Попытаюсь объяснить это.

Comment: Я по своей серости не знаю, кто такая эта графиня Саксонская и чем она прославилась в России, но это точно не про себя Елизавета говорит, у неё такого титула не было. А коли так, то значения "в качестве" у "как" тут нет, а есть "подобно тому, (как)". Запятая перед "как" зрительно отсылает именно к этому правилу, но она-то должна бы стоять пере "тем более", где она и так есть. Таким образом, зрительно запятая перед "как" только в водит в сомнение относительно структуры фразы.

Comment: Спасибо, Бегемотус! Не зря она мне глаз резала.))